# How to display grouped data in two table by crystal report

Tags: wpf, winforms, crystal-reports

I hope to display grouped data in two table, like following:
[image]

It much like following format:

```
Group 1:
table 1    table2
1 A        5 E
2 B        6 F
3 C
4 D
```

It's like the folding of data, once left side table is fully , and then put the data into right side.
In the above case, the data group has six elements, they are {(1,A),(2,B),(3,C),(4,D),(5,E),(6,F)}
Is cystral report support that? And how to meet it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, I try to use subgroup and put them in both side,
the new problem I meet is the linked parameter what I used is formula, and its content is `{PaymentInfo.M_D}+{PaymentInfo.generalOrderGroup}+{PaymentInfo.examName}`. However, I don't know why this value is always showing on the subgroup title, like following:
[image]

How to hide this infos and delete the upper and bottom empty section, thanks a lot.